# How can I eliminate the grouping div used in nested flexboxes?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML where I want the logo on the left and everything else on the right.

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__logo">logo</div>
  <div class="header__controls">
    <div class="header__link">link 1</div>
    <div class="header__link">link 2</div>
    <div class="header__link">link 3</div>
    <div class="header__selector">
      <span class="header__selectorbutton">en</span>
      <div class="header__selectordropdown">
        <a href="#">Francais</a>
        <a href="#">Pirate</a>
        <a href="#">Chef</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  &__logo {
  }
  &__controls {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  &__link {
    text-align: center;
    background: cyan;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  &__selector {
    text-align: center;
    background: silver;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: 1rem;

    .header__selectordropdown {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      right:0;

      a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;

        &:hover {
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
      }
    }
     &:hover {
       .header__selectorbutton {
         background: yellow;
       }
       .header__selectordropdown {
        display: block;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to do a few things to remove the `header__controls` div but I can't seem to get it working correctly.  I think this can be done nicer with *CSS Grids*, but the layout when I tried failed as well.

https://codepen.io/trajano/pen/mdyYPaM

Ideally I want the HTML to look like

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__logo">logo</div>
  <a href="#" class="header__link">long_link</a>
  <a href="#" class="header__link">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="header__link">link 3</a>

  <span class="header__selectorbutton">en</span>
  <div class="header__selectordropdown">
    <a href="#">Francais</a>
    <a href="#">Pirate</a>
    <a href="#">Chef</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely, the `header__selectordropdown` wrapper is required for the funtionality you require but the `header__controls` is not.

You can push the controls to the right by adding `margin-right:auto` to the logo.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
}

.header__logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header__link {
  text-align: center;
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.header__selector {
  text-align: center;
  background: silver;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.header__selector .header__selectordropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.header__selector .header__selectordropdown a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.header__selector .header__selectordropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header__selector:hover .header__selectorbutton {
  background: yellow;
}

.header__selector:hover .header__selectordropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__logo">logo</div>
  <div class="header__link">link 1</div>
  <div class="header__link">link 2</div>
  <div class="header__link">link 3</div>
  <div class="header__selector">
    <span class="header__selectorbutton">en</span>
    <div class="header__selectordropdown">
      <a href="#">Francais</a>
      <a href="#">Pirate</a>
      <a href="#">Chef</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```